# How to get a combined string from multiple files

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have in folder multiple rtf files. I want to read all and convert them to a single string.

I can open them one by one using following code.

```
Const ForReading = 1
sFolder = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PLR\"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
  If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "rtf" Then 
    set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(oFile)
        Do While oFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = oFile.ReadAll
    Msgbox TextLine
    Loop
  End if
Next
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

Now I want to have final string from all files that contain all the files in the folder.

Like
Textall = Textline1+textline2...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are reading all of the lines, you can just concatenate them on like below instead of

```
TextLine = oFile.ReadAll
```

you could use

```
TextLine = TextLine & oFile.ReadAll
```

Comment: Hmm. Let me validate it. I think it worked. Thanks man. I'll see if any other problem with regards to this happens. Will accept soon.